# xamarin android c# Edittext scroll to bottom automatically

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext

i want to scroll automatically to the bottom in a Edittext.

i found nothing in the web about it. Its only about the ListView.

Is there any solution to do it with the Edittext?

Thank you

Comment: Hey, are you tried this - make edittext focus when you want to scroll down to edittext?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EditText.ScrollTo` method and calculate the scrollY that you needed:

```
etMain = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etMain);
...


//get the lineHeight
int lineHeight = etMain.LineHeight;
//get the line Count
int lineCount = etMain.LineCount+1;
//calculate the scrollY;
int scrollY = lineHeight * lineCount;
//scroll to the bottom
etMain.ScrollTo(0, scrollY);
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried it with ScrollTo but it doesnt work.

But with RequestFocus it worked :)

Thank you